# Chi Squared Distribution Test in Excel

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio, chi-squared-distribution

I calculated a likelihood ratio on two likelihoods from my research (LhRatio = 2 * (Time Slice Lh – Normal Lh)). I'm testing a model which is a special case of my null meaning my likelihood ratio should be equal to a chi square statistic. I therefore tested my LR with the Chi Square Dist formula on excel (CHISQ.DIST(B7,2, TRUE)). What do my output values tell me? Some example values i've received are 0.3 and 0.9.

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].